# Ubuntu 14.04 Can't update

Tags: 14.04, updates

A red citcle is showing up on the top of the screen to le me know that an updated failed but when i tell it to show me the [Updates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Lgq6.png) its empty but says there is 38mb that needs to be downloaded when i click on update i get this [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLBRC.png).

I have restarted the system and it keeps popping back up i all so did an update with terminal but that did not help.

How do i fix this?

Comment: Can you post the error you got when you tried via terminal?

Comment: There was no Error from terminal but the red citcle keeps popping back up.

Comment: What's the output of `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install -f`?

Comment: sudo apt-get update shows this 1.http://i.imgur.com/AI79JoP.png   2.http://i.imgur.com/AI79JoP.png  3.http://i.imgur.com/xUZwX2c.png  (sorry if that's a lot , i did not know if you wanted to see everything)                                    sudo apt-get install -f shows http://i.imgur.com/bEqbYdU.png

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following:

1) Try another software sources location:

- Open Ubuntu Software Center
- Menu: Edit
- Software Sources
- Download From
- Select United States
- Restart your system and retry installing the updates.

2) Try to fix broken packages (in terminal -> [CTRL] + [T])

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade 

sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Hope this will help you out. You could also check the repositories when you are looking at the Software Sources, making sure they are valid (especially ones you added yourself).

Good luck!

Comment: :( did not help.

Comment: Strange because the images you added in your comment don't show any errors or anything. What does the original "details" tell you in the upgrade window? (see first image in your question) Might simply be that the 6 "not upgraded" be the problem. Maybe if you can figure out what they are you could trey remove and then reinstall them. Hopefully this is shown in the details on the update screen.

Comment: The details don't show anything . i tried to to  do sudo apt-get dist-upgrade  and its coming back with an error (http://i.imgur.com/0E8F53D.png) i don't know if this has anything to do with what's going on or not,

Comment: Looks like it could be 3rd-party repositories during the upgrade ([link]http://www.noobslab.com/2015/04/how-to-upgrade-to-ubuntu-1504-vivid.html) although not something very useful to you now... Still looking for more options but starting to look like a hard problem to solve. You could try to install the dependencies yourself by the way. Could you try that?

Comment: You also might want to have a look here: (https://blog.bramp.net/post/2012/04/29/failed-ubuntu-update/)

Comment: With all the time i spent trying to fix this i  may cut my losses and reinstall. thanks to everyone that tried to help,

Comment: That is just what I also do and  keeps my system nice and clean.